# ¿ Como saber si un numero es 100% natural?

Tags: javascript, string, ecmascript-6

estoy haciendo un reto en [codewars](https://www.codewars.com/kata/55f8a9c06c018a0d6e000132/train/javascript) que trata de lo siguiente:

> Los cajeros automáticos permiten códigos PIN de 4 o 6 dígitos y los códigos PIN no pueden contener más que exactamente 4 dígitos o exactamente 6 dígitos.
>   Si se pasa una cadena de PIN válida a la función, devuelve verdadero, de lo contrario devuelve falso.

Básicamente tiene que ser un PIN de 4 o 6 dígitos, que sea positivo, que no sea con decimal sino que tiene que ser entero y que solo sean números. Mi problema es que me devuelve `verdadero` en los números decimales cuando tendría que dar `falso`. Por favor si alguien me ayuda y me explica mi error se lo agradeceria

```js
function validatePIN (pin) {
    let num,result, long = pin.length, expresion = /.-+[a-z]/
     long === 4 || long === 6 && !expresion.test(pin) ? num = parseInt(pin)
                                                      : result = false;
                                          
    Number.isSafeInteger(num) && num >= 0 ? result = true 
                                          : result = false;
    console.log(num)
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Pero que es lo que tratas de hacer con esa expresión regular? En particular `.-+` no hace lo que tú crees

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function validatePIN (pin) {
   
    let longitud = pin.length
    //expresión regular, busca cualquier combinación de digitos
    //desde el inicio hasta el final de la línea
    let expr = /^\d+$/
    
    //si todas las condiciones se cumplen retorna true
    return (longitud ==4 || longitud == 6) && expr.test(pin);
}

console.log(validatePIN("12345"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Asegurate de lo que llega es string:

```
function validatePIN(pin) {
  const spin = pin + ""; // to string
  let num,
    result,
    long = pin.length,
    expresion = /.-+[a-z]/;
    console.log(spin);
  long === 4 || (long === 6 && !expresion.test(pin))
    ? (num = parseInt(spin))
    : (result = false);

  Number.isSafeInteger(num) && num >= 0 ? (result = true) : (result = false);
  console.log(num);
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Si agregas una explicación de que hace tu código no solo te apegas a [answer] sino que además haces fácil y comprensible de entender tu aporte a quien pregunto y futuros visitantes

Answer (score 1):

Aquí hay una aplicación de prueba simple que pasa todas las pruebas en su página de codewars. Tiene tres pasos:

1. Primero verifica que la entrada sea una cadena
2. Luego, verifica si la longitud es 4 o 6
3. Luego, verifica si todos los caracteres de la cadena son dígitos

El código:

```
function validatePIN (pin) {
  if (typeof pin !== "string") return false;
  let len = pin.length;
  return (len === 4 || len === 6) && /^\d+$/.test(pin);
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido. No te preocupes si español no es perfecto pero ten en cuenta que las reglas del sitio desaconsejan incluir contenido que no ayude a hacer más clara las publicaciones incluyendo saludos, firmas y disculpas.

Answer (score 0):

En realidad lo que haría sería convertir los digitos explícitamente a un string y contar la cantidad de caracteres. Si son 4 o 6, validar si el pin es un entero o un flotante.

```
function validatePIN (pin) {
  let number = String(pin);

  if(number.length ==4 || number.length==6)
    return Number.isInteger(pin);

  return false;
}
```